# What year or Which year?

Tags: questions, interrogatives

I am a bit confused between "What year or Which year" Below are some examples, although all seems correct to me. I hope someone can explain what is correct and why?

Which year is a leap year?

What year is a leap year?

What is your birth year?

I can't remember which year it was.

I can't remember what year it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "what" for an open question - one where the other person must answer from their knowledge or memory.

Use "which" for a multiple-choice question, or where the answer can only come from a limited range of options.

The latter doesn't necessarily mean you present the options with the question - for example "which British monarch reigned from 1189 to 1199" is appropriate because the answer can only come from a limited range of people.

Regarding your examples:

1. Your first example is a bit complex because there is not just one leap year - there is one every four years, so both are a bit odd. If you were looking at a limited range of 4 years, you might ask **which** was a leap year, because only 1 of the 4 can be. Otherwise, looking forward or back, I would ask "which *years* were leap years".
2. A person's birth year could be anything, so I would ask "**what** was your birth year".
3. Both could be correct, depending on context. If someone is trying to recall a specific year from a limited time period, then "I can't remember which year it was" would be right. But if the focus of the statement was on a memory or thing that happened, then you might say as an aside "I can't remember what year it was".

Comment: I will also add that this applies to statements as well an "open" statement like "I can't remember what year it was." sounds better with "what" in my opinion; and a statement with options would use "which" such as: "I know it was 1989 or 1990, but I do not know which."

Comment: so in my question I mentioned "what is correct", it means I should say "which is correct", thanks for the help, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **which** and **what**.

We use **which** when we are choosing between a small number. **Which year**

We use **what** when we are choosing between a large number. **What year**

**Which**- there is a restricted range of answers.

**What**- the range of answers is not restricted.

Which Farukh? Farukh the banker or Farukh the teacher? (NOT What Farukh)

What is the capital of Canada? (NOT which is the...)

Which is the capital of Canada? Ottawa or Toronto? (NOT What is the...)

Which would you prefer-- wine or beer? (NOT what...)

What would you like to eat? (NOT Which...)